# TinyMCE is not working correctly in my django project

Tags: python, django, tinymce, blogs, tinymce-5

I have created a Django blog site where I can write blog posts both from the main site and the admin site. To compose my blog posts, I am using the TinyMCE editor. When I am in the admin site, I can successfully write and submit my blog posts using TinyMCE. However, when I attempt to write a blog post from the main site using TinyMCE, I encounter an issue. Although my submit button appears to be working correctly, it does not perform any action upon clicking it. Strangely, if I refresh the page and then click the submit button again, my blog post gets posted, and everything works fine from that point onward.

Please tell me What is the mistake that I'm doing.
This is my tiny.js file

```
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
script.src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js";
document.head.appendChild(script);

script.onload=function(){
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#id_content",
    height:656,
    plugins: [
        'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
        'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
        'table emoticons template paste help'
      ],
      toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | ' +
        'bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | ' +
        'forecolor backcolor emoticons | help',
      menu: {
        favs: {title: 'My Favorites', items: 'code visualaid | searchreplace | emoticons'}
      },
      menubar: 'favs file edit view insert format tools table help',
      content_css: 'css/content.css'
    });
}
```

and these are all the js files of my site.

```
    <script src="{% static 'tiny.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/flatpickr.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/aos.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/tiny-slider.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/glightbox.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/navbar.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/counter.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/custom.js' %}"></script>
```

And this is my createBlog.html template from where i create and post my blogs from my main site.

```
{% extends 'basic.html' %}
{% block title %}Create Post{% endblock title %}
{% load static %}
{% load django_bootstrap5 %}
{% block content %}


<div class="col-md-10 container">
    <div class="p-3 py-5">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
            <h4 class="text-right">Create Post</h4>
        </div>
        <form method="POST"   enctype="multipart/form-data">

            {% csrf_token %}

            {% bootstrap_form form %}


            <div class="mt-5 text-center"><button id = "checktbn" class="btn btn-primary profile-button" type="submit">Post Now</button></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

And this is my postcreateview() from my views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'slug','category', 'content']
    template_name = 'blog/create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        messages.success(self.request, 'Post created successfully!')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Please tell me what im doing wrong,i can write blog and post it with the help of tinyMCE but when i
try to write and post from my main site then button is not doing anything..mind you my button is working fine as i have tried it using AddEventListner.. and yeah when i remove tinyMCE  then i can write and Post my blogs without any problem.. but i dont want to remove tinyMCE please help me.

..
please have a look at my images:-
1.This is my create blog page from where any user can write their blogs..here i can write my blog but when i click to submit button nothing happens.

[main site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x19RO.png)

2.And this is my admin site..here i can create blog and save it

[Admin site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT1aA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here I already created a project on integration TinyMCE with a Django clone repo from [here](https://github.com/Mahammadhusain/djangotinymce.git)

for more information refer pypi package [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-tinymce-4/)

##### in Admin Panel

[image]

##### Browser Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying.. actually i know how to add tinymce with my blog..i have added it to my admin site.. the problem is that..when i write blog from admin site it works perfectly and i can save my blog from there.. but when i try to write and save my blog using tinymce from main site( where every user can post their blog) then I'm unable to save it..nothing happens after clicking the save button

Comment: Please see all the images that i have linked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying. Actually I know how to add tinymce with my blog, I have added it to my admin site.

The problem is that, when I write blog from admin site it works perfectly and I can save my blog from there. But when I try to write and save my blog using tinymce from main site ( where every user can post their blog ) then I'm unable to save it, nothing happens after clicking the save button.